# ruby on rails know when you come from a redirect_back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I would like to know if there's any way to know when you come from a redirect_back. I would like to show a popup on my html if I come from here:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  def addproduct
     (session[:products] ||= []) << params[:item]
     redirect_back(fallback_location: "/")
  end

 end
```

There is any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but it can work, the definition of [redirect_back](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back) accepts a `fallback_location` and `args`. So maybe you can use `flash` to pass an argument like:

```
# controller
redirect_back(fallback_location: "/", flash: { from_add_product: true } )

# view
<% if flash[:from_add_product] %>
  # show popup
<% end %>
```

Another option is to use `request.referer` to check the url like:

```
# view or a helper
<% if request.referer && request.referer =~ /payments\/addproduct/ %>
  # show popup
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.referrer`.

You can see the controller and action (method) which you come from using `request[:controller]` and/or `request[:action]`.

Put it in your `app/layouts/application.html.erb` and you'll be able to see each referrer:

```
<%= request[:controller] %>
<%= request[:action] %>
```

Comment: I've edited recently, check it adding the code in your `application.html.erb`, this way you can use it in controllers as you want.

Comment: Like this? <%= if request[:payments] %> show popup <% end %>

Comment: Maybe `<%= if request[:controller] == 'payments' %>...<% end %>`, you need to check for the controller name.

Comment: Did you print the `request[:controller]` to check what's the output?

Comment: I was checking it right now, and it always print series that's the controller of this series.html.erb

Comment: So, you're not redirecting from `PaymentsController` you could try checking for the `Series` as controller and any method as action with `request[:action]`.

Comment: request[:action] gives me always home, and request[:controller] always series. I'm redirecting with the code that i've shown before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144792/discussion-between-sebastian-palma-and-lechucico).